# How do I call a function inside another function in the same file in Python?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to break up some code into smaller subprograms within the same file to make it more modular. This is the code I would like to break up:

```
def time():
    print("This program calculates the number of seconds in a given length of 
        time.\n")
    second = 1
    minute = second * 60
    hour = minute * 60
    day = hour * 24
    week = day * 7
    number1 = (eval(input("Enter a number of weeks: ")))
    calc1 = number1 * week
    number2 = (eval(input("Enter a number of days: ")))
    calc2 = number2 * day
    number3 = (eval(input("Enter a number of hours: ")))
    calc3 = number3 * hour
    number4 = (eval(input("Enter a number of minutes: ")))
    calc4 = number4 * minute
    number5 = (eval(input("Enter a number of seconds: ")))
    calc5 = number5 * second
    sum1 = (calc1 + calc2 + calc3 +calc4 + calc5)
    print("\nIn", number1, "week(s),", number2, "day(s),", number3, "hour(s),", 
        number4, "minute(s), and", number5, "second(s), there are", sum1, 
        "second(s).")
```

It works the way I want it to when it's all together, but I'd like to break it up somewhere along the lines of this:

```
def count():
    print("This program calculates the number of seconds in a given length of 
        time.\n")
    second = 1
    minute = second * 60
    hour = minute * 60
    day = hour * 24
    week = day * 7

def number():
    number1 = (eval(input("Enter a number of weeks: ")))
    calc1 = number1 * week
    number2 = (eval(input("Enter a number of days: ")))
    calc2 = number2 * day
    number3 = (eval(input("Enter a number of hours: ")))
    calc3 = number3 * hour
    number4 = (eval(input("Enter a number of minutes: ")))
    calc4 = number4 * minute
    number5 = (eval(input("Enter a number of seconds: ")))
    calc5 = number5 * second
    sum1 = (calc1 + calc2 + calc3 +calc4 + calc5)

def time():
    print("This program calculates the number of seconds in a given length of 
        time.")
    count()
    number()
    print("In,", number1, "weeks,", number2, "days,", number3, "hours,", 
        number4, "minutes, and", number5, "seconds, there are", sum1, 
        "seconds.")

time()
```

The goal is to run time() and have it call count() and number(), so the code for time() isn't as long. (I know the original code isn't that long, but I'm trying to learn how all this works.)

I've had success calling functions within a file before, but only when it was to print a string, and no math was involved. I've tried playing around with parameters and return and googling and even some gnashing of teeth, but to no avail. I keep ending up with errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#525>", line 1, in <module>
    time()
  File "<pyshell#524>", line 4, in time
    number()
  File "<pyshell#522>", line 3, in number
    calc1 = number1 * week
NameError: name 'week' is not defined
```

I'm new to programming so I'm sure I'm missing something annoyingly simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own and would appreciate any help.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but you should be using `int` instead of `eval` to convert the `input`ted string into an integer.

Comment: use `week` as a global var

Comment: When you break a code into smaller chunks, variable management must be one of your major concerns. You have too many of them to split it into different functions. @d9ngle, really? Global variables is your solution?

Comment: a [whirlwind](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/a-whirlwind-tour-of-python.csp) tour of python and the scipy lecture [notes](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/language/python_language.html) are good introductions to Python

Comment: Just pass the required information to your functions via arguments. You could have one function that asks the user for input, and another function that takes a seconds, minutes, hours, days and weeks argument, and returns the total number of seconds for the given values. The input handling function gathers input, passes it to the calculate-seconds function, which returns the total number of seconds, so the input handling function can print the result.

Comment: @volcano module-level constants would be an idiomatic place to store values like these. Python isn't Java or C++.

Comment: @das-g, I am not sure what an "idiomatic place" is, but the value in qeustion was variable set in function

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like the big thing you need to learn about is scope. When you declare a variable inside a function, you can only use that variable inside that function. So for example, when you declare week inside of the count function, you can only access the variable "week" when you are inside the function.

If you want to access a variable from anywhere inside a program you need to declare it globally. Here is a working version of your code with the time variables declared globally.

```
print("This program calculates the number of seconds in a given length of time.\n")
second = 1
minute = second * 60
hour = minute * 60
day = hour * 24
week = day * 7

def number():
    number1 = (int(input("Enter a number of weeks: ")))
    calc1 = number1 * week
    number2 = (int(input("Enter a number of days: ")))
    calc2 = number2 * day
    number3 = (int(input("Enter a number of hours: ")))
    calc3 = number3 * hour
    number4 = (int(input("Enter a number of minutes: ")))
    calc4 = number4 * minute
    number5 = (int(input("Enter a number of seconds: ")))
    calc5 = number5 * second
    sum1 = (calc1 + calc2 + calc3 +calc4 + calc5)
    print("In,", number1, "weeks,", number2, "days,", number3, "hours,",
        number4, "minutes, and", number5, "seconds, there are", sum1,
        "seconds.")

def time():
    print("This program calculates the number of seconds in a given length of time.")
    number()


time()
```

You need to be careful with global variables as you can run into problems if you use too many of them. Before trying to write more complicated programs I would recommend reading [this article](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html) that does a good job explaining how scope and namespaces work in python.

Comment: This definitely worked better, thank you! And thank you for the article.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: ... within the same file to make it more modular

**You don't need a `def count()` at all.**
All `values` are constant and therefore should be defined so.
There is no need to compute the `values` over and over again.

You can make it more modular, for instance:

```
SECONDS = {'s':1, 'm': 1*60, 'h':60*60, 'd':60*60*24, 'w': 60*60*24*7}
def get_input():
    result = {'sum1':0}
    for cat in ['weeks', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']:
        value = int( input( "Enter a number of {}: ".format(cat) ))
        result[cat] = value
        result['sum1'] += SECONDS[ cat[:1] ] * value
    return result

def time():
    result = get_input()
    print("\nIn, {weeks}, week(s), {days}, day(s), {hours}, hour(s),"
          " {minutes}, minute(s), and, {seconds} second(s), "
          "there are, {sum1} second(s)."\
          .format(**result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("This program calculates the number of seconds in a given length of time.\n")
    time()
```

It's common, to use always a **`__main__`** entry point.
This gives you the ability to call `def get_input()` from other python scripts.

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Answer (score 0):

You could have your `count` return a `dict`, like:

```
def count():
    times = {'second': 1}
    times['minute'] = times['second'] * 60
    times['hour'] = times['minute'] * 60
    times['day'] = times['hour'] * 24
    times['week'] = times['day'] * 7
    return times
```

Then you can call `count` in the `time` and pass it to `number`:

```
def time():
    ...
    times = count()
    values = number(times)



def number(times):
    values = {}
    number1 = int(input("Enter a number of weeks: "))
    calc1 = number1 * times['week']
    values.update({'number1': number1, 'calc1': calc1})
    ...
    sum1 = calc1 + calc2 + calc3 + calc4 + calc5
    values['sum1'] = sum1
    return values
```

And then you can use the returned dict from number to populate your print at the end of `time`